# Compute expression node in dataflow :exceeded max error limit:

Tags: einstein-analytics, dataflow

I am using the below query in compute expression in dataflow:

```
case when Date_Taken is null then toDate(Date_Received, "yyyy-MM-dd") else toDate(Date_Taken, "yyyy-MM-dd") end
```

*Type:Date*

*Format:yyyy-MM-dd*

**I am encountering the below error :**

> Something went wrong while executing the compute:SampleHeader node: exceeded max error limit: The number of failed rows exceeded the 10000 limit. Only the dataflow owner or users with the View All Data permission can download the log. (02K0r0000009ZcIEAU_03C0r000000HXN7EAO)

Answer (score 0):

In your expression can you check for blank Date_Taken in addition to null or check in the dataset for the  existence of values as you are expecting in Date_Taken. I am suspecting a mismatch there.

Answer (score 0):

I used coalesce function as below and it worked for me :

```
coalesce(toDate(Date_Taken_sec_epoch),toDate(Date_Received_sec_epoch))
```

Comment: Not clear about the "it worked for me" part of the solution.  What coalesce did was only to replace null values (when encountered Date_Taken_sec_epoch) with value as toDate(Date_Received_sec_epoch). Is this ok per the logic you are trying to build using the computeExpression?

Comment: Yes I wanted the first non -null value from Date_Taken and Date_Received . In the first case also, I was doing the same thing , I was storing Date_Recieved if Date_Taken was null else I was storing Date_Taken itself